I keep running into the NoReverseMatch error when running my program, it is an online auction site, how do I handle this error?
So I am making an auction site and everything is working fine , the problem I keep running into is when I try to place a new bid it gives the noreversematch error for 'addwatchlist'which is a button and url to add an item on auction to your waatchlist. The thing is the button works fine and you can add and remove items from the watchlist easily, but when I enter a new bid it gives me the noreversematch error for that url and I don't know why.
I tried checking for errors like typos and differnt ways to call a url pattern but nothing seems to be working, what I'm expecting when placing a new bid is that the bid will be updated and entered into the database but instead it gives me the error. Yes the bid is being saved in the django/admin site. I will psate the code here below for the view function and the template calling the url.
urls.py
    path("addWatchlist/<int:id>/", views.addWatchlist, name="addWatchlist"),

views.py
    def addWatchlist(request, id):
         listing_data = get_object_or_404(Listing,pk=id)
         user = request.user`
         listing_data.watchlist.add(user)`
         return redirect(reverse("listing", args=(id, )))

Template
          {% else %}
             <form action="{% url 'addWatchlist' id=Listing.id %}" method="POST">
                 {% csrf_token %}
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add to watchlist</button>
             </form>

          {% endif %}`

ERROR messgae displayed
NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:
Reverse for 'addWatchlist' with keyword arguments '{'id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['addWatchlist/(?P[0-9]+)/\Z']
highlighted code
`25              <form action="{% url 'addWatchlist' id=Listing.id %}" method="POST">`


@Sayse looks like in this case, the template is trying to generate support for a keyword argument, but the code is set up to expect a positional argument - yes? (I don't use Django.) OP might need some more specific guidance WRT how that choice is made.

@KarlKnechtel - Its because the id isn't an integer but an empty string - see '{'id': ''}', Most likely Listing.id is None or doesn't exist
